# Form not submitting with AJAX

Tags: javascript, php, ajax, forms, post

=====UPDATE AGAIN==== (if anyone cares!)
the solution I posted before stopped working for whatever reason. I included a beforeSend in my ajax request and pasted the portion of my js that validates my form into it. Works like a charm now!

```
$('#form').on('submit', function(e) {
e.preventDefault(); //prevents page refresh
         $.ajax({
        type: "post",
        beforeSend: function(){ // check that form is complete
                        },
        url: "client_config_send2.php",
        data: $(this).serialize(),
        success:  function(data){
            alert('Thank you'); hide_request();window.location = "#top";
        }
       });
   });
```

**EDIT**

See my answer below, using 2 .preventDefault!

I have read through many pages / examples of this, but for some reason I can't get it to work on "my" form.
I'm simply trying to submit my form without refreshing the page or opening a new page / tab for the confirmation message.
The form:

```
<form id="form" name="Configurator" method="post" action="">
.... //Client configures his product, display an image if they choose, and request a quote.
<button id="submit_button" type="submit" name="Submit" >Request</button>
</form>
```

The client_config_send2.php works, it simply pulls a bunch of parameters from the form (configuration, contact info) and puts it into an email. This part works fine before I try to integrate the ajax.

The JS:

```
$('form').on('submit', function(e) {
e.preventDefault();     
if(!validateForm(this)){
return true;
}

$.ajax({
        type: "post",
        url: "client_config_send2.php",
        data: $(this).serialize(),
        done:  function(data){
            alert("Thank you, we will get back to you shortly");
}
        });

})  


</script>
```

The validateForm() function also works, it checks if the configuration is valid, if the email / contact info is complete, etc.
At this point, the validateForm works: if info is missing, the alert pops up. However when validateForm() returns true, the form doesn't submit, nothing happens.

I have tried success instead of done, return false instead of true in the JS, and many other things I found online but I am lost. Never used AJAX before so I'm not 100% confident with the subtleties of the language!

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Is the url correct? Try this, type the url in a browser and click enter. Does this returns anything?

Comment: Open Up Your Console, click on the network tab, then submit the form, you should see the request happen. What is the status code of the response?

Answer (score 0):

"client_config_send2.php" is a filename. The URL you give to Ajax needs to be, well, a URL like http://example.com/client_config_send2.php.

Comment: There are two kind of URLs, he used the "relative" type but yours is "absolute". Anyway if his form is in the same folder of clien....php his url should work

Comment: I've heard of relative and absolute **paths**, but not URLs. Without the host as part of the URL, how is the network going to find the host?

Comment: URLs and paths are kind of same things

Comment: yes, the php is in the same folder and the relative address worked before I tried ajax.

Comment: Did you check that client_config_send2.php is (1) receiving anything and (2) responding?

Comment: Also, using just the file name will only work if "client_config_send2.php" is in the same directory as the page from which the Ajax call is being made. Is that true?

Comment: If your .php is receiving something, then the $.ajax is working. How do you respond? Also, relevant to another comment, it is "success". "done" is not valid jQuery AFAIK.

Comment: @bobdye I do receive the complete email now, so the php and the ajax works. Just not the way I want it to right now!
At this point I need to a) display an alert at success, b) if possible prevent the page from refreshing.

Comment: Well, if you change "done" to "success", you should see the alert. The page should not be refreshing with the code above.

Comment: @bobdye my final code is at the end. I had to include another .preventDefault to stop the page from refreshing. Thanks for your help! I will try again with success but I couldnt get it to work before.

Answer (score 0):

Change done to success:

```
success:  function(data){
```

success only fires after your request got response and the response code is OK(http 200).

Comment: tried that as well. I had read that "success" was now outdated, but regardless, it doesn't work. Thanks anyway!

Answer (score 0):

Update the code below:

```
$('form').on('submit', function(e) {
e.preventDefault();     
if(!validateForm(this)){
return true;
}
var formdata = $(this).serialize();

$.ajax({
        type: "post",
        url: "http://www.example.com/client_config_send2.php",
        data: formdata,
        success:  function(data){
            alert("Thank you, we will get back to you shortly");
}
        });

})  


</script>
```

Comment: no luck :( updated the "example.com" obviously, but nothing. validateForm() still works, but nothing happens when I click the submit button

Answer (score 0):

Could you try removing/commenting event.preventDefault();

If this method is called, the default action of the event will not be triggered. (http://api.jquery.com/event.preventdefault/)

Comment: if I remove the preventDefault the form gets submitted whether the validateForm() function returns true or false. In simple words, I get an email with half the info missing!

Answer (score 0):

Try coding in the following format. The logic uses an if/else statement to make the ajax call.

```
$('form').on('submit', function(e) {
    //If form could not be validated
    if(!validateForm(this)){
       //prevent the form form submitting
        alert("Your form is not valid for submission!");
        e.preventDefault();  
    }
    //else 
    else{
        //form input is valid
        //make the ajax call
        $.ajax({
            type: "post",
            url: "client_config_send2.php",
            data: $(this).serialize(),
            done:  function(data){
                alert("Thank you, we will get back to you shortly");
            }
           });
       }
    });
 });
```

Comment: Thanks for your help. Doesn't quite work yet though. if validateFrom return false, it returns the alert (good). When it does validate though, it still returns the error and does not submit. I'll do some more tweaking, I know I'm very close to a solution :)

Comment: I tweaked your code a bit and got it to work:
    $('form').on('submit', function(e) {
 var x = validateForm();
    if(x == false){
        ...
    });
the submit works when validateForm is true, it doesn't open a new tab (good!) but refreshes the page and loses all the info the customer has entered (bad). 
Thanks for your help, off to more googling to find out how to "save" the info after the ajax!
EDIT: the confirmation alert however does not show.

Answer (score 0):

Here is the final code that does exactly what I want:
- the validateForm() function works as it should. If the form is not complete, it returns false, an alert pops up and the form does not submit
- if validateForm() returns true, the form gets submitted, the confirmation alert pops up and the page does NOT refresh. Users can then build a new configuration and submit a new request without re-entering all the contact info.

The 2 .preventDefault did the trick!

```
$('form').on('submit', function(e) {
e.preventDefault(); //prevents page refresh when form is submitted
//If form could not be validated
var x = validateForm();
if(x == false){
   //prevent the form form submitting
    e.preventDefault();  
}
//else 
else {
    //form input is valid
    //make the ajax call
    $.ajax({
        type: "post",
        url: "client_config_send2.php",
        data: $(this).serialize(),
        success:  function(data){
            alert('Thank you! we will get back to you within 24 hours. Please check your junk / spam folder if you do not receive a response within that time.');
        }
       });
   }
});
```

Thanks everyone for your help!