# Ajax send my form when it's being submitted

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I am working on a little project where I have an ajax call that should submit my form without refreshing the page (or redirect me to another page), the problem I however stumble upon is: The ajax function doesn't respond when I click on submit.

The ajax code looks a bit odd (for example the }); in the eBlock call, but that is because it contains code in that part aswell... but not code that would be usefull for this post I think.

my ajax code:

```
function saveExercise() {
$('.eBlock').each(function (i, contents) {
    //lots of code here
});

$.ajax({
    url: 'saveJson.php',
    type: 'POST',
    data: eBlock,
    dataType: 'json',
}).done(function (response) {

});
}
```

my form:

```
<form  id='my_form' class="container-fluid" action="" method="POST" required>
   <button id='resetInputs' type='button' onclick='getResetInputs()' class='btn btn-danger fa fa-refresh fa-2x resetInputs'></button>
   <button type='submit' id='saveBtn' class='btn btn-info fa fa-download fa-2x saveBtn' required name="submit" onclick="saveExercise()"></button>
</form>
```

not sure if this is any info you could use, but the ajax call is in a javascript file.

EDIT: Yes, I have been researching preventdefault(); I even looked for the same problem and found [Form not submitting with AJAX](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28386910/form-not-submitting-with-ajax) this post related to the same problem I have.

Further changes have been: took out the window.location part. kept the .done however in case needed.

Comment: You've to call the function in which the ajax code lies, on the `onclick` event of submit button.

Comment: Now you just have to call the `saveExercise()` function on the onclick event, like `onclick="saveExercise()"`

Comment: as you can see, I do so, but it still refreshes. like, on the page itself.

Comment: That's because you have used `window.location = 'index.php';
`. It's actually redirecting, not refreshing the page. Just remove that line and it will not refresh.

Comment: You neglected to prevent the event default - when you click a submit button, the browser submits the form, so far, so obvious. If you don’t want that, then you have to explicitly prevent it. (Go research how, please, that’s been discussed countless times already.)

Comment: Took it out, still looks like it is redirecting, already tried refreshing with CTR SHIFT R. should I take out the part from .done aswell ? I feel empty headed asking so much haha

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do like this:
JS code:

```
    $('#my_form').submit(function(event){
        event.preventDefault();

        var data = yourFunctionToGetTheData();

        $.ajax({
            url: url,
            type: "POST",
            dataType: 'json’,
            data: data,
            success: function(result){
            }
        });
    });
```

HTML code:

```
  <form  id='my_form' class="container-fluid" action="" method="post" required>
       <button id='resetInputs' type='button' onclick='getResetInputs()' class='btn btn-danger fa fa-refresh fa-2x resetInputs'></button>
       <input type='submit' class='btn btn-info fa fa-download fa-2x saveBtn' required name="submit"></button>
  </form>
```

Comment: my script was "refreshing" because I had made a fadeIn keyframe. in my CSS I had @keyframes fadeIn from opacity 0 to opacity 1. I think that would reload when the page would be submitted. or do you think this wasnt the case and it still is not functioning?

Answer (score 1):

You can use jquery to listen to the submit event of your form element and then run the ajax request like this:

```
$("#my_form").submit(function(e){
     $.ajax({
         url: 'saveJson.php',
         type: 'POST',
         data: eBlock,
         dataType: 'json',
     }).done(function (response) {
        window.location = 'index.php';
     });
})
```

Comment: But when I do so, the functionality of my website becomes 0, in which I mean I lose buttons (I am trying to make everything as much as possible with javascript and jquery and not with html). I could show you all the code that's implemented with the ajax call combined, but the post would most likely end up with "You have given too much bullshit code" and would be voted down and stuff.

Comment: In that case you need to create a listener to onClick of a button. for example $('#btn-id').click and then feed it the ajax request inside a function

Comment: oh wait, I can just add the function the ajax call is in.