# Ajax doesn't submit my form, but does submit through action

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ajax

I am working on a project and already made a post regarding to ajax but I didn't want to change the subject of my post, so I thought making a new one would be the best. My ajax call doesn't work I believe. Why do I think so? when I insert the fil directly into my form (action="X") it works... kind of, but that's another story. but when I insert it into my ajax it doesn't send anything over to my JSON.

my ajax (I used the one from the previous post);

```
 function saveExercise() {
     // more not related code
 }

 $('.eBlock').each(function (i, contents) {
  //some code thats inside this function but not related
 });

$('#my_form').submit(function(event) {
      event.preventDefault();
      $.ajax({
         url: 'writeJson.php',
         type: 'POST',
         data: eBlock,
         dataType: 'json',
         succes: function(result) {

         }
      })
 });
```

my HTML;

```
<form  id='my_form' class="container-fluid" action="" method="POST" required>
     <button id='resetInputs' type='button' onclick='getResetInputs()' class='btn btn-danger fa fa-refresh fa-2x resetInputs'></button>
     <button type='submit' id='saveBtn' class='btn btn-info fa fa-download fa-2x saveBtn' required name="submit"></button>
</form>
```

I have been looking around: [Form not submitting with AJAX](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28386910/form-not-submitting-with-ajax)

https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/189241/cant-trigger-an-ajax-function-with-a-submit-button-in-the-dashboard

every bit of code related to eBlock, where I call the function, what the purpose is, what it does. I am sorry for the confusion and late response.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  var id = 0;
  var addOpdracht = $('<a/>', {
 'class': 'btn btn-success',
 'id': 'addOpdracht'
}).on('click', function() {
 $('form').append(getExerciseBlock(id));
});


function getExerciseBlock(i){
  var eBlock = $('<div/>',{
 'id': i,
 'class': 'col-md-12 eBlock'
});

 $(eBlock).append(getRemoveBtnExercise(i), getAudioBtn(i), getWordInput(i), 
  getWordPartInput(i), getWordPartInput(i), getRemoveBtn(i), 
 getAddBtn(eBlock, i));

  return eBlock;
}
```

Comment: `required` has no meaning on `form` and `button` elements. Also, where is `eBlock` defined

Comment: Required was something I was testing with (forgot to take it out I guess) and eBlock is where all my buttons (these are made with functions etc.) get append to. would you like to see that piece of code aswell?

Comment: Please show us how you are creating `eBlock`

Comment: You need to show the code that declares and initializes `eBlock`. Also, have you tried your code with the Developer Tools open to the Network tab to verify that the AJAX request is **not** getting made?

Comment: Whats the point of the non related code? The sintax is totally broken.

Comment: @ScottMarcus no I haven't. Didn't even know about it (absolute newbie to ajax) and I can update the post to show the eBlock.

Comment: And, if you are also asking about a CSS issue, where's the CSS?

Comment: Open your developer's tools in your browser by hitting `F12` and then click to the "Network" tab. Try your code in this configuration and see if a request for `writeJson.php` appears. Also, AJAX requests only work when made over `http` or `https`, so you must be testing on a server.

Comment: @muecas the function so you would know there is a function, and the comment that shows how there is code in between certain parts. so you atleast know I have it in a function etc. I don't see much non related code to be honest. I just tried to fit the ajax call in the function etc. as natural as possible for you to get a view as clarified as possible.  yes, I am working on a server (school related hands on the job expierence etc.) I guess ill just update the whole post

Comment: You also have a syntax error in your AJAX configuration. `succes` instead of `success`. And, the code you've posted has an extra `}` at the  end of it.

Comment: That's not a syntax error.  It just will not register anything.  You can give any key value pairs to the jquery ajax method and it will ignore anything it does not expect.

Comment: @Taplar Well, it's not a *JavaScript* syntax error, but it is an error with the syntax of JQuery's `$.ajax()` method.

Comment: `<button type='submit'..` will submit the form whether or not ajax does its thing.  Change this to `<button type='button'` to stop the form from being submitted by the browser then handle the button click.

Comment: @freedomn-m The first line of code in the `form`'s submit event handler is to cancel the event, so that's not an issue.

Comment: Ok, so there is one issues I see.  `eBlock` is a dom element in a jQuery object, which isn't what you want to send on an ajax request.

Comment: Next thing is to add is an error handler: `error: function(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) { console.log(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown); }`

Comment: Now that you've posted the code about `eBlock` we can see that you've declared the variable inside of the `getExerciseBlock` function and so the variable won't be available outside of it.

Comment: And, you can't pass a jQuery element as `data` for an ajax call. It must be an object or a String formatted as querystring.

Comment: You really need to edit your question again and include the code that ***calls*** `getExerciseBlock()` as well. Please don't just add more EDITs to your question, organize your code.

Comment: The `e.preventDefault()` won't be applied if there's a exception in the script (eg a variable not defined).  Make sure you turn *on* `preserve log` (chrome, equivalent in other browsers) in the browser console to see errors over post backs.

Answer (score 0):

Let's see the code:

```
$('#my_form').submit(function(event) {
      event.preventDefault();
      $.ajax({
         url: 'writeJson.php',
         type: 'POST',
         data: eBlock,
         dataType: 'json',
         succes: function(result) {

         }
      })
 });
```

Problems:

- you are using succes instead of success, which will never be executed
- success is deprecated since jQuery 1.5 and you will need to use done instead
- eBlock is a variable and we do not see its initialization. Judging by its name, it is highly probable that eBlock is a jquery object, you will need to pass a simple object or a querystring

#### Fix

```
$('#my_form').submit(function(event) {
      event.preventDefault();
      $.ajax({
         url: 'writeJson.php',
         type: 'POST',
         data: {},
         dataType: 'json',
      }).done(response) {
          console.log(response);
      }
 });
```

#### Improvement

Let's mine all the items in the form having a name:

```
$('#my_form').submit(function(event) {
      event.preventDefault();
      var data = {};
      var items = $(this).find("[name]");
      for (var i = 0; i < items.length; i++) {
          var v = items[index].value;
          if (items[index].tagName.toLowerCase() === "input") {
              if (items[index].type === "checkbox") {
                  v = items[index].checked;
              }
          }
          data.push(items[index].name + "=" + v);          
      }
      $.ajax({
         url: 'writeJson.php',
         type: 'POST',
         data: data,
         dataType: 'json',
      }).done(response) {
          console.log(response);
      }
 });
```

Comment: my apologies for reacting so late, eBlock is where are the functions get add. I can show it to you. (every bits of code related to it)